# Remove a dimension from some variables in an xarray Dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have an xarray Dataset where some variables have more dimensions than necessary (e.g., a 3D dataset where the "latitude" and "longitude" variables also vary along time). How do I remove the extra dimensions?

For example, in the dataset below, 'bar' is a 2D variable along the `x` and `y` axes, with constant values along the `x` axis. How do I remove the `x` dimension from 'bar' but not 'foo'?

```
>>> ds = xr.Dataset({'foo': (('x', 'y'), np.random.randn(2, 3))},
                    {'x': [1, 2], 'y': [1, 2, 3],
                     'bar': (('x', 'y'), [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]])})
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) int64 1 2 3
    bar      (x, y) int64 4 5 6 4 5 6
Data variables:
    foo      (x, y) float64 -0.9595 0.6704 -1.047 0.9948 0.8241 1.643
```

Answer (score 15):

The most direct way to remove the extra dimension (using indexing) results in a slightly confusing error message:

```
>>> ds['bar'] = ds['bar'].sel(x=1)
ValueError: dimension 'x' already exists as a scalar variable
```

The problem is that when you do indexing in xarray, it keeps around indexed coordinates as scalar coordinates:

```
>>> ds['bar'].sel(x=1)
<xarray.DataArray 'bar' (y: 3)>
array([4, 5, 6])
Coordinates:
    x        int64 1
  * y        (y) int64 1 2 3
    bar      (y) int64 4 5 6
```

This is often useful, but in this case the scalar coordinate `'x'` on the indexed array conflicts with the non-scalar coordinate (and dimension) `'x'` when you try to set it on the original dataset. Hence xarray errors instead of overriding the variable.

To get around this, you need to drop the scalar `'x'` after indexing. In the current version of xarray, you can do this with `drop`:

```
>>> ds['bar'] = ds['bar'].sel(x=1).drop('x')
>>> ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64 1 2
  * y        (y) int64 1 2 3
    bar      (y) int64 4 5 6
Data variables:
    foo      (x, y) float64 -0.9595 0.6704 -1.047 0.9948 0.8241 1.643
```

In future versions of xarray (v0.9 and later), you will be able to drop coordinates when indexing by writing `drop=True`, e.g., `ds['bar'].sel(x=1, drop=True)`.